# Combining certain strings in an array based on positive matches against mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multidimensional array composed of strings of various length as follow:

```
$a = 
Array ( [0]
   Array ( [0] AQWER, [1] CFG, [2] JUHTYREWQ, [3] K, [4] LO ),
Array   [1]
   Array ( [0] VFG, [1] yhtredw, [2] koeutydjwiq, [3] bg, [4] hytefs, [5] M),
Array   [2]
   Array ( [0] BHTWQ, [1] BH, [2] NJUy))
```

Equally, I have a mySQL table containing the following values

```
myTable
AQWER
CFG
JUHTYREWQ_K_LO
VFG
yhtredw
bg_hytefs
BHTWQ
BH_ NJUy
```

## Desired outcome

I am trying to test and reformulate the array based on matches in the SQL table so that it looks like this:

```
$a =
Array ( [0]
   Array ( [0] AQWER, [1] CFG, [2] JUHTYREWQ_K_LO ),
Array   [1]
   Array ( [0] VFG, [1] yhtredw, [2] koeutydjwiq, [3] bg_hytefs, [5] M),
Array   [2]
   Array ( [0] BHTWQ, [1] BH_NJUy))
```

And to still show values that have not been found (e.g. koeutydjwiq)

## What I have tried so far:

I received great help in helping me manipulate `$a` so as to be able to test 1 string, 2 strings and 3 strings combinations.

However my code does not successfully pick up string combinations (that are definitely there in both the Array and the Table) and as a result, does not reformat the original array `$a` and I can't quite figure out why.

In fact more specifically, when calling the `print_r($para)` in the IF statements, I get `.........`

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($a as $val) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($val); $i++) {
            // A_B_C
            if (isset($val[$i+2])) {
                $exagon = array();
                $exagon = $val[$i] . '_' . $val[$i+1] . '_' . $val[$i+2];

                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","myDB");
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE LIST = '".$exagon."'";

                $para = array(
                    );

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                //echo $result;

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $para[] = array($row['LIST']);
                }

                if (isset($para) && !empty($para)) {
                    print_r($para);
                    array_splice($a, $i, $i+2, $para);
                    $i=$i+2;
                }
                else {
                    unset($para);
                    unset($exagon);
                }



            }
            // A_B
            elseif (isset($val[$i+1])) {
                $exagon = array();
                $exagon =  $val[$i] . '_' . $val[$i+1];

                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","myDB");
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE LIST = '".$exagon."'";

                $para = array(
                    );

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $para[] = array($row['LIST']);
                }

                if (isset($para) && !empty($para)) {
                    print_r($para);
                    array_splice($a, $i, $i+1, $para);
                    $i=$i+1;
                }
                else {
                    unset($para);
                }

            }
            // A
            else {
                echo $val[$i];
            }
        }
}
```

Admittedly, through research, I have found posts and manuals to guide me on using array_splice and calling out variables in a SQL query but it is quite possible multiple errors are present in this code

Comment: above array is static or dynamic

Comment: Hello, it is static

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code. theses dynamic array also it's work check with your array data it's working fine

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","myDB");
//These will create commbination
$finalArray = array();
$sampleArray = array(array('AQWER','CFG','JUHTYREWQ','K','LO'),array('mno','xxy','kkl'));
foreach($sampleArray as $key=>$val){
    $combincationArr = array();
    foreach($val as $k1=>$v1){

        $combincationArr[] = $v1;
        $prevStr = $v1;
        for ($i=($k1+1); $i<(count($val)); $i++) {
            $prevStr .= '_'.$val[$i];
            $combincationArr[] = $prevStr;
        }

    }
    if(!empty($combincationArr)){
           $finalArray[$key] = $combincationArr;
    }
}
$destArr = array();
foreach($finalArray as $key=>$val){
    if(!empty($val)){
    $para = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE FIND_IN_SET (LIST,'".  implode(',', $val)."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $para[] = array($row['LIST']);
    }

    $destArr[] = $para;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($destArr);die;
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out again. It did not quite work; I get an error Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given and then blank arrays

Comment: check my update code is it work or not please confirom

Comment: thanks for the revision, i still get the same error. I also now get this error as well Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: sorry I am not quite sure how to paste the error. it seems the issue is with the .explode argument using $val array? Can this be parsed as a string?

Comment: just replace explode with implode

Comment: thanks that solved the error but having run the code against my array, the results are not quite there. It omitted strings with no match and added all possible matches (all possible combinations). Whereas I wanted to re-write the array with the first found combination (e.g. IF it find A_B_C, ignore the other scenario and replace A, B, C with A_B_C, ELSE IF it finds A_B, replace A, B with A_B and so on

Comment: why you don't want to find other condition?

Comment: see above code dynamically work logically only these way we can do